# How to get submit form button to be on the next line css?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a simple form in the React with two inputs and a submit button.  I would like the button centralised below the two inputs but can't get this working at all. Could someone please help?

HTML

```css
.SearchBar-fields {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 2.88rem;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.SearchBar-fields input {
  width: 21rem;
  padding: .66rem 1rem;
  margin-right: 2.22rem;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: .77rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  align-self: stretch;
}

.SearchBar-fields input:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}


.SearchBar-submit button {
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: .72rem 1.7rem;
  background-color: #cca353;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 600;
  transition: background-color .5s;
  border-radius: 20px;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form className="SearchBar-fields" onSubmit = {handleSearch}>
    <input placeholder="Search Businesses" onChange = {handleTermChange} required/>
    <input placeholder="Where?" onChange = {hanldeLocationChange} required />
    <div className="SearchBar-submit">
        <button >Let's Go</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE** **TWO WAYS TO DO THIS:**

**Main problem that you are facing is because of form element, which takes the full width of the container being the `block-level element`.**

**1. Use extra wrapper `div` around your inputs and set display:flex; on your wrapper.**

```css
.SearchBar-fields{
  display: inline-flex;
}

.SearchBar-fields input {
  width: 21rem;
  padding: .66rem 1rem;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: .77rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.SearchBar-submit {
  text-align:center;
}
.SearchBar-submit button {
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: .72rem 1.7rem;
  background-color: #cca353;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 600;
  transition: background-color .5s;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-top:1rem;
}
```

```html
<form class="SearchBar-fields" onSubmit = {handleSearch}>
    <div class="inner-wrapper">
     <input placeholder="Search Businesses" onChange = {handleTermChange} required/>
     <input placeholder="Where?" onChange = {hanldeLocationChange} required />
     <div>
    <div class="SearchBar-submit">
        <button >Let's Go</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I have fixed this issue by using `display:flex;` on `form` and using a wrapper around inputs.

**2. Second method**:

Try making your `.SearchBar-fields` form as `display:inline-block`, so that the form grows input widths long only.

And after that you have `.SearchBar-submit` div, which contains your button, you can simply use `text-align:center`, on the `div` and button will move to center. There are many other ways, also but this is simple and straight forward.

```css
form.SearchBar-fields {
  margin-bottom: 2.88rem;
}

.SearchBar-fields input {
  width: 21rem;
  padding: .66rem 1rem;
  margin-right: 2.22rem;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: .77rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  align-self: stretch;
}

.SearchBar-fields input:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}


.SearchBar-submit {
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: .72rem 1.7rem;
  background-color: #cca353;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 600;
  transition: background-color .5s;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<form className="SearchBar-fields" onSubmit = {handleSearch} style="display:inline-block">
<input placeholder="Search Businesses" onChange = {handleTermChange} required/>
<input placeholder="Where?" onChange = {hanldeLocationChange} required />
<div className="SearchBar-submit" style="text-align:center">
    <button >Let's Go</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you! Little bit of a "bodge" with the input margins and this worked perfectly, Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Use the `display: flex` property.
If you change the following snippets it should be working.

html

```
<form className="SearchBar-fields flex flex-c " onSubmit = {handleSearch}>
    <input placeholder="Search Businesses" onChange = {handleTermChange} required/>
    <input placeholder="Where?" onChange = {hanldeLocationChange} required />
    <div className="SearchBar-submit flex content-centered">
        <button >Let's Go</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

css

```
.SearchBar-fields {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 2.88rem;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 21rem;
}

.SearchBar-fields input {
  padding: .66rem 1rem;
  margin-right: 2.22rem;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: .77rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  align-self: stretch;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-c {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content-centered {
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this (tested and works):

```
 <div className="fullDiv">
  <form className="SearchBar-fields">
    <div className="inputDiv">
      <input placeholder="Search Businesses" />
      <input placeholder="Where?" />
    </div>
    <div className="SearchBar-submit">
      <button>Let's Go</button>
    </div>
  </form>
 </div>
```

Many of the CSS problems you will encounter can easily be rescued by adding more specific divs around each unique block of html. It's also considered proper practice (tip for the future)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the button inside a div and give it

```
display: flex; justigy-content: center; min-width: 100%
```